# How does this nested ternary expression work?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, clamp

I was making a clamp() function in php, and decided to go for a nested ternary expression just to try it. 
In the end, I settled with this (working) function :

```
function clamp($value, $min, $max){
    return 
          $value<$min ? $min
        : ($value>$max ? $max
        : $value);
}
```

However, why are the brackets around the second expression required? I had tried removing them afterward :..

```
function clamp($value, $min, $max){
    return 
          $value<$min ? $min
        : $value>$max ? $max
        : $value;
}
```

... but in this version, it will return `$max` if `$value` is smaller than `$min`. I just don't understand how it comes to that result.

Comment: This is why: http://phpsadness.com/sad/30

Comment: PHP has the associativity of the ternary backwards compared to every other language, meaning that you can't chain them without parens and get a sane result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hear of php having "left associativity" with ternary, though I never understood what it meant:

Take
`$bool ? "a" : $bool ? "b" : "c"`
Right associativity is: `$bool ? "a" :` `($bool ? "b" : "c")`
Left associativity is : `($bool ? "a" : $bool)` `? "b" : "c"`
So in the end php will always it evaluate to either b or c.

Bonus:
`$bool ? $bool ? "c" : "b" : "a"`
Here is a syntax that I think wouldn't change meaning based on associativity. 
I wonder whether people managed to find a pretty indentation for this variant.